# SQL query with 3 tables returns duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hopefully this won't get flagged as duplicate. I am struggling to understand the return of duplicate rows when more than 2 tables are in query. I have read a number of similar questions and posts online but can't wrap my head around the logic. I am hoping that if someone could explain with my specific use case, it should finally sink in.

I have 3 tables

```
[dbo].[Branch](
    [ContractorCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BranchNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BranchName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    ...
    [HealthBoardID] [int] NULL
```

```
[dbo].[OutstandingCount](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EnteredOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,    
    [Branch] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [productGroup] [int] NULL,  
    [Product] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL, 
    ...
    [Satisfied] [bit] NOT NULL
```

```
[dbo].[TargetLineCount](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Branch] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductGroup] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TargetCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
```

There is a 1:M relation from Branch table to OutstandingCount table and there is a 1:1 relation from Branch table to TargetLineCount table

What I need to return is by branch
how many items are still to count so how many rows in OutstandingCount with Satisfied = 0
how many items are added to the count each day, this is decided by the branch and product group.

This is my query

```
SELECT b.BranchName,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.ProductGroup = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [NHS to count],
MAX(CASE WHEN t.ProductGroup = 'DISP' THEN t.TargetCount ELSE 0 END) AS [NHS daily count],
SUM(CASE WHEN o.ProductGroup = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [OTC to count],
MAX(CASE WHEN t.ProductGroup = 'OTC' THEN t.TargetCount ELSE 0 END) AS [OTC daily count]
FROM OutstandingCount o
INNER JOIN Branch b ON o.Branch = b.BranchName
INNER JOIN TargetLineCount t ON t.Branch = b.BranchNumber
WHERE o.Satisfied = 0 AND o.EnteredOn < '2022-07-01'
GROUP BY b.BranchNumber,b.BranchName
ORDER BY b.BranchNumber
```

The target counts return correct, e.g. for branch 1 the [NHS/OTC daily count] is 7 and branch 2 it is 8. However the [NHS/OTC to count] figures are doubled, e.g. branch 1 should be 65 but is 130, branch 2 should be 7 but is 14.

As I say, it is all coming from my lack of understanding how to treat multiple table joins. If I request either of the data separately, I get the desired result, it is only when I try and get all the information in a single query I struggle.

Sample data and output:

Branch:

| ContractorCode | BranchNumber | BranchName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | Branch1 |
| 5465 | 2 | Branch2 |

OutstandingCount:

| Id | EnteredOn | Branch | ProductGroup | Product | Satisfied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9990 | 2022-07-01 | Branch1 | 1 | pr55 | 0 |
| 9991 | 2022-07-01 | Branch1 | 1 | pr60 | 0 |
| 9992 | 2022-07-02 | Branch1 | 2 | pr78 | 0 |
| 9993 | 2022-07-01 | Branch2 | 1 | pr55 | 0 |
| 9995 | 2022-07-02 | Branch2 | 1 | pr78 | 0 |
| 9996 | 2022-07-02 | Branch2 | 2 | pr30 | 0 |
| 9998 | 2022-07-03 | Branch2 | 2 | pr55 | 1 |

TargetLineCount:

| ID | Branch | ProductGroup | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | PG1 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | PG2 | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | PG1 | 8 |
| 5 | 2 | PG2 | 8 |

Desired Result would be:

| Branch | NHS To Count | NHS Daily Count | OTC To Count | OTC Daily Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Branch1 | 1 | 10 | 2 | 7 |
| Branch2 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 8 |

In explanation - Branch1 has no satisfied items so we have 2 from ProductGroup1 to count and 1 from ProductGroup2. Branch2 has 1 satisfied so we count 2 for ProductGroup1 and 1 for ProductGroup2. The to count figures from the TargetLineCount table are a 1:1 so there is only one value for Branch1 for ProductGroup1 and one value for Branch1 for ProductGroup2.

**Solution:**

Thanks to the help from Dragon, my specific issue needed me to add a further table for joining and then extend the queries to use that table as well

```
INNER JOIN ProductGroup p ON p.Branch = b.ContractorCode AND p.ProdGroupID = o.productGroup

INNER JOIN TargetLineCount t ON t.Branch = b.BranchNumber AND t.ProductGroup = p.Description
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a many to one relationship and you expect SQL Server to only `COUNT`/`SUM` a row once, when it's returned multiple times. That isn't how aggregate functions work. Likely you need to pre-aggregate, but without consumable sample data and expected results, we don't know what your SQL actually need to look like

Comment: you select BranchName and then some aggregates, but GROUP BY b.BranchNumber,b.BranchName  Looks strange

Comment: @Sergey , As I need to order by branch number, SQL-Server requires the order by clause(s) be in the group by

Comment: @Larnu, you are correct. There is a 1:M for one join and a 1:1 for another, I have added to the question text. I use sum as it is easier to read IMO but in essence, yes, I want to count the rows in the table with many rows for a single value in the other table.

Comment: So yes, pre-aggregate (in a CTE or derived table). Again, though, *without consumable sample data and expected results, we don't know what your SQL actually needs to look like*.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you, I have added sample data and desired outcome

Comment: The tables in my edit preview are formatted correctly, I don't know why they are displaying like this in the question

Comment: Because [so] refuse to fix the preview window, is the short answer, @Colin-G-Davidson . It's a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596/397219) that they simply haven't addressed and seem to have literally no interest in doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what the issue is.

It is with your join

```
INNER JOIN TargetLineCount t ON t.Branch = b.BranchNumber
```

It should be like this:

```
INNER JOIN TargetLineCount t ON t.Branch = b.BranchNumber AND o.ProductGroup = t.ProductGroup
```

The only thing is the Product Group connection between TargetLineCount and OutstandingCount doesn't appear to be shown properly in your example as one is a varchar and the other is an int?

Comment: Thank you, I have added sample data and a desired output to the question. The query you attached as expected brings back everything which for the real data set is 20,000+ rows with each column from the 3 tables being outputted. As assumed in the question, each row from OutstandingCount is being returned twice, this is why the counts are all doubled.

Comment: @Colin-G-Davidson I modified my answered since you provided the sample data and expected output

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible that the issue is actually the tables themselves. Sadly I inherited them as is but thankfully I am in the process of creating new ones to combat the multiple issues I have found. The varchar and int issue you mention is because their is another table I excluded as I wasn't pulling it in as I didn't think it was needed. This table would link those 2 fields as it has rows e.g. ProductGroupId 1 | PG1 so that is how those links would be made. Saldy including that table and altering the join as per your answer still returns the same value of double rows

Comment: Thank you again for the assistance. You led me to the point, I appreciate the knowledge of the underlying dataset was confusing. For anyone with a similar issue, I had added my specific solution to the question.